# WPF - show window in Action

Tags: wpf

I have a small problem. I have method which register global hotkey, when I press hotkey, program call Action. In Action method I would like Show window, but don't work it.
This is my code:

MainWindow.cs:

```
_hotKeyRegistrator.Add(Modifier.Ctrl, Keys.A, () => {Show();}
```

HotkeyRegistrator.cs:

```
public class HotkeyRegistrator
{
    private HwndSource _source;
    private readonly WindowInteropHelper _windowInteropHelper;
    private const int HotkeyId = 9000;
    private const int WmHotkey = 0x0312;
    private List<HotKey> _hotKeys;

    public HotkeyRegistrator(Window window)
    {
        _windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
        _source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(_windowInteropHelper.Handle);
        _source?.AddHook(HwndHook);
        _hotKeys = new List<HotKey>();
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey([In] IntPtr hWnd, [In] int id, [In] uint fsModifiers, [In] uint vk);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey([In] IntPtr hWnd, [In] int id);


    public void Add(Modifiers modifier, Keys key, Action action)
        => _hotKeys.Add(new HotKey(HotkeyId + _hotKeys.Count, modifier, key, action));

    public void Register()
    {
        foreach (var hotKey in _hotKeys)
        {
            if (!RegisterHotKey(_windowInteropHelper.Handle, hotKey.Id, hotKey.Modifier, hotKey.Key))
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot register hotkey");
            }
        }
    }

    public void UnRegisterAll()
    {
        _source.RemoveHook(HwndHook);
        _source = null;
        foreach (var hotKey in _hotKeys)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(_windowInteropHelper.Handle, hotKey.Id);
        }
        _hotKeys = null;
    }

    private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == WmHotkey)
            _hotKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == wParam.ToInt32())?.Action.Invoke();
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

Hotkey.cs:

```
public class HotKey
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public uint Modifier { get; }
    public uint Key { get; }
    public Action Action { get; }

    public HotKey(int id, Modifiers modifier, Keys key, Action action)
    {
        Id = id;
        Modifier = (uint)modifier;
        Key = (uint)key;
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Action method is called using Invoke method. When I press CTRL + A, call action and Show method, but window dont open.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: "Action method is called using Invoke method": Can you show us the code where Action method is called using Invoke method?

Comment: Thank you. If you put a breakpoint on `Show()` in `()=>{Show();}`, does it hit the breakpoint when you press `Ctrl+A`?

Comment: Yes, breakpoint is there. Try this simple example in window constructor, dont work too:             Action a = new Action(() =>
            {
                Show();
            });
            a.Invoke();

Comment: Sounds like `Show()` just doesn't work.

Comment: No, when you call Show normally it works

Comment: Can you create a minimal, verifiable example which demonstrates `Show()` working when called, while also demonstrating `Show()` *not* working when called from an `Action`? It doesn't have to do both at once; one of the options could be commented out while testing the other one.

Comment: Yes, `Show()` not working from Action.

Comment: Never say never, but I'm going to need some persuasion on that point. Are you invoking the action from a thread other than the UI thread?

Comment: Good question, I dont know how to work `Action.Invoke()` method. Maybey invoking in another thread.

Comment: How and where were you constructing the window when you tested this code in the constructor: `Action a = new Action(() => { Show(); }); a.Invoke();` ?

Comment: You can insert this code to constructor of MainWindow

Comment: What code are you referring to?

Comment: What window are you intending to open? I guess the MainWindow is already visible and shown and when the Show method is called...?

Comment: Have you tried putting the Action in a try catch clause to check if you get an exception to get more details? Maybe you aren't using the UI dispatcher because you are in another thread. You can put the UI dispatcher in your constructor of the MainWindow in a private field and use  it when showing the "action window"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. My window has set `WindowState="Minimized"` attribute on startup. When I would like call `Show()` after press global shortcut, code must be this:

```
_hotKeyRegistrator.Add(Modifier.Ctrl, Keys.A, () => {
    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    Show();
});
```